# I'm having trouble POSTING a JSON string to a url for the output in JSON

Tags: php, json, http, http-post

I'm trying to make a post request to this URL:

```
http://clan.z8games.com/clanServices.asmx/getPlayerPublicInfo
```

with this JSON string

```
{"usn":12434525}
```

to get an output similar to this;

```
 {"d":"{\"usn\":12434525,\"nick\":\"Guiness\",\"lev\":39,\"playCnt\":3734,\"winCnt\":3210,\"loseCnt\":239,\"enemyKillCnt\":129734,\"deathCnt\":5140,\"exp\":1072522,\"headshotKillCnt\":120339,\"friendKillCnt\":5,\"escapeCnt\":45,\"regDate\":\"2011\",\"lastPlayDate\":\"2012-08-12\",\"guildid\":217089,\"clanName\":\"Guiness™\",\"memberType\":null,\"gcClanID\":55000,\"hs5p\":202,\"fk1p\":0,\"k10p\":211,\"d20p\":2,\"esc4p\":0,\"sv3p\":676,\"matchLosses\":98,\"matchWins\":1894}"}
```

because I making a datascraper for game accounts (like stats) and each page is different based on the account ID.

I tried this:

```
<?php 
$usn=$_GET["accountUSN"]; 
$url='http://clan.z8games.com/clanServices.asmx/getPlayerPublicInfo';

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => "POST",
        'content' => http_build_query(
            array(
                'usn'=>$usn
             )
        )
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result =  file_get_contents($url,NULL,$context);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Someone suggested this but it always returns

```
bool(false)
```

I just want to know how to do this properly, if it makes you feel any better I don't really want any full code. Also, I'm trying to avoid cURL and I'd like a native option.

Also, someone was trying to help me here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920064/php-simple-html-dom-parser-not-giving-me-text-for-a-td
but I accidentally deleted the post, being a new user. How can I undelete this?

EDIT:

```
<?php

$usn=$_GET['accountUSN'];
$url='http://clan.z8games.com/clanServices.asmx/getPlayerPublicInfo';

$options=array('http'=>array('method'=>'POST','content'=>'content' => '{\'usn\':$usn}'));

$context=stream_context_create($options);
$result=file_get_contents($url,NULL,$context);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

server error.

Comment: You are sending content as a query string not a json string

Comment: can you explain? i don't understand :( I query for the account number, because it looks like this:http://clan.z8games.com/charstat_cf.aspx?usn=12434525 but after the page loads theres an ajax call to the link i posted in OP getting all the player data.

Comment: `http_build_query` will give you `usn=12434525`, if you want json you can use `'content' => "{\"usn\":$usn}"`

Comment: I tried what you said and I get a server error.

Comment: I looked a the service you're trying to use and It uses SOAP not JSON see http://clan.z8games.com/clanServices.asmx?op=getPlayerPublicInfo

Comment: wow. How can I tackle this now? I examined this in fiddler and it was giving me a json string. BTW thank you for helping me sir.

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) might help.

Comment: can you give me example.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've used this is to open the file, then get the stream content from the file pointer.

```
$context = stream_context_create($options); 
$fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $context);
if (!$fp) {
   die('Failed to open stream');
}
$result = stream_get_contents($fp);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use firebug,see Net tab ,compare what you programmatically sent and what browser sent.
Make sure that you sent what it want.